# Fibonacci sequence proof, how should I proceed?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers

Given the Fibonacci sequence   $F_{0}=0 \;,\; F_{1}=1 \;,\;  F_{n+2}= F_{n+1}+ F_{n+1} ; \;\; n\geq 0$

Prove that $ \sum _{i=1}^{2n}F_{i}F_{i-1} = F_{2n}^{2}\\$

Base Cases:   $ F_{1}F_{0} = F_{0}^{2}\\ 0 = 0 \\    F_{2}F_{1} = F_{2}^{2}\\ 1 = 1   $

Which are true.

Now, with  $\;n=k\;$  we have the inductive step,

$ \sum _{i=1}^{2k}F_{i}F_{i-1} = F_{2k}^{2}\\$

We have to prove then that for $n = k+1$

$ \sum _{i=1}^{2k+2}F_{i}F_{i-1} = F_{2k+2}^{2}\\$

We can do the following:

$ F_{2k+2}F_{2k+1} +\sum _{i=1}^{2k}F_{i}F_{i-1} = F_{2k+2}^{2}\\$

and from the inductive step we can do,
$ F_{2k+2}F_{2k+1} +  F_{2k}^{2}= F_{2k+2}^{2}\\$

I get stuck here, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum _{i=1}^{2(k+1)}F_{i}F_{i-1} &= F_{2k+2}F_{2k+1} + F_{2k+1}F_{2k} + \sum_{i=1}^{2k}F_{i}F_{i-1}\\
&=F_{2k+2}F_{2k+1} + F_{2k+1}F_{2k}+F_{2k}^2\\
&=F_{2k+2}F_{2k+1} + F_{2k}(F_{2k+1}+F_{2k})\\
&=F_{2k+2}F_{2k+1} + F_{2k}(F_{2k+2})\\
&=F_{2k+2}(F_{2k+1} + F_{2k})\\
&=F_{2k+2}(F_{2k+2})\\
&=F_{2k+2}^2
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a term in the sum for $n=k+1$. It should be
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2k+2}F_{i}F_{i-1} = F_{2k+1}F_{2k} + F_{2k+2}F_{2k+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{2k}F_{i}F_{i-1}\,.
$$

Now try see if you can finish the proof.

Comment: That is very true, thank you/